# Magento 2 read custom xml file from third party server and load it in our magento site

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, xml, magento2.3

I am loading custom xml feed file myfeed.xml from third party server. This file is publically accessible.  Not any authentication set.

```
 <valley street name="jackson">

   <item>
       <name>Product 1</name>
       <description> Description 1</description>
   </item>
            <name>Product 2</name>
       <description> Description 2</description>
   <item>

   </item>
       <name>Product 3</name>
       <description> Description 3</description>

    <item>

    </item>


 </valley>
```

How to read all item nodes from the valley?  I need help to read this xml data magento 2 standard method way not php method or class.

I know how to create custom configuration file and process it but i want to check if any other method available to read the xml and process it.

Is there any native magento2  class that allows me to read custom xml?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can conver your `XML` to `PHP` Array using following code:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlstring, "SimpleXMLElement", LIBXML_NOCDATA);
$json = json_encode($xml);
$array = json_decode($json,TRUE);
```

May be this will help you.

NOTE: your `XML` format should be correct.

Comment: I already know this way as well.  i want to know is there any magento native class or library that allows me to do so?  

I want to manage backward compatibility as well. so prefer the magento based code